# WebRTC video from a remote iPhone not rendered on iPhone 12 (iOS 14)

Tags: ios, iphone, webrtc

I have a video chat app using WebRTC. The app runs on iOS and Android phones/tablets. Recently I upgraded to
iPhone 12 (iOS 14), and discovered if the remote device
is Android or iPad running iOS 12, I can render their
video on the local iPhone 12. But if the remote device
is iPhone, then the remote iPhone's video is not rendered on the local iPhone 12 (the remote iPhone can render the iPhone 12 video). The local video is rendered on iPhone 2, and the audio between the remote and local iPhones is working too.

I'm using RTCEAGLVideoView to render local and remote
videos. I got the remote RTCVideoTrack via:

func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didStartReceivingOn transceiver: RTCRtpTransceiver);

Comment: Never mind the question. I solved the issue by adding the following line of code after creating the local videoSource:    videoSource.adaptOutputFormat(toWidth: 1280, height: 720, fps: 30);

Comment: Thank you Terry! I was facing the same problem.